# Site serving static files but not media files in Prod

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

My local server is able to pick media files using `] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

but site is not able to find them, and give error 404.

Folder `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` contains `site.conf`

File `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf` contains:

```
Alias /static /www/site/static
<Directory /www/site/static>
    Require all granted

</Directory>

Alias /media /www/site/media
<Directory /www/site/media>
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

I can find a static files on url generated as `http://site/static/imgs/img.png`
but getting error 404 with url generated as `http://site/media/imgs/img.png`

In second scenario: 
all the files look same, but from file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`
I removed the media part and left with

```
Alias /static /www/site/static
<Directory /www/site/static>
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

Now server serves the media files with debug turned on, but gives 404 with debug turned off. 
which is even more confusing.

How can I serve media files on server, with debug turned off?

The image files are dynamically getting generated and getting uploaded in the folder in both the scenarios. 
Static files are also served perfectly in both scenarios.

Comment: Try adding trailing slashes to the alias lines, like: `Alias /media/ /www/site/media/` and see if that works https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: tried with `Alias /media/ /www/site/media/` and
 `Alias /media/ /www/site/media` but both did not work.

Comment: What permissions does the directory and the files have?